# How to revoke a PDF digital certificate while the signature is still valid?

Tags: certificate

I've been looking for guidelines regarding my question to no avail because I couldn't think of a proper combination of keywords to filter out irrelevant results.

Suppose I have issued a document in some PDF format, signed by an implementation of some digital signature technology. The validity of the document is contingent upon the holder complying to certain rules. Once such compliance has been found to be broken, I'd like to revoke the document. How do I go about doing that?

I don't want to revoke my 'digital certificate' (of the X.509 kind) associated with the signature of that document. I just want to invalidate the document, whose invalid status would be apparent upon verification.

If I were to go the [Verifiable Credentials](https://www.w3.org/TR/vc-data-model/) route instead, the scenario can be implemented through the property `credentialStatus` along with some revocation infrastructure. I'm trying to think of an equivalent way in the conventional PDF world. Could you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot revoke **the document** as revocation mechanisms are only specified and implemented for identities (better said certificates unsing trust chains and certificate revocation lists - see [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)).

Comment: I see. That’s very clear. I suspected as much. Thank you!